# Bootstrap Table using ajax not sorting or searching

Tags: bootstrap-table

I am using a simple bootstrap Table with data loading from ajax. I assume I am not using the data correctly in loading it into the columns and that is what is breaking it from sorting and searching. Can someone please help. This is what my code is-

`

```
<table id="table"></table>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {     
                $.ajax({
                   url: 'http://dev.cehtp.org/api/water/get/3301477',
                   dataType: 'json',
                   success: function(jsnData) {
                       $('#table').bootstrapTable({
                          data: jsnData.rows, //this seems to be my problem area
                          columns: [{
                                field: 'id',
                                title: 'Id',
                                sortable: true,
                              searchable:true
                            }, {
                              field: 'name',
                              title: 'name',
                              sortable: true,
                              searchable:true
                          }]
                       });
                   }
                });
            });
            </script>
```

`